# How to combine my three query?

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I have 3 query to find my data. But i can't combine to 1 query and get my data. what should I do with my query? please help me, thanks.

```
SELECT distinct pk_pgw_master, fk_kelas, rombel, pk_matpel, nama_rombel as wali_kelas, null as row_group
FROM pgw_master
LEFT JOIN akd_program_ajar ON pgw_master.pk_pgw_master = akd_program_ajar.fk_pgw_master
LEFT JOIN akd_matpel ON akd_program_ajar.fk_matpel = akd_matpel.pk_matpel
LEFT JOIN akd_pengajar ON pgw_master.pk_pgw_master = akd_pengajar.fk_pgw_master
LEFT JOIN akd_wali_kelas ON akd_pengajar.pk_pengajar = akd_wali_kelas.fk_pengajar
LEFT JOIN akd_akademisi ON akd_akademisi.kode_rombel = akd_program_ajar.rombel
WHERE pk_pgw_master = 'pgw050'
```

second query :

```
SELECT count(pk_kompetensi_dasar) as jml_kd FROM akd_kompetensi_dasar where fk_mapel='MP1610004' and fk_kelas='2'
```

3rd query :

```
SELECT count(pk_akademisi) as jumlah_siswa FROM akd_akademisi where kode_rombel='XI TPTL 1'
```

[this is three result from 3 query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5VFG.png)

how can I get 1 result?

Comment: Mysql is different from Sql Server. Which one are you really using

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, I am using SQL Server not MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aliasing all queries and Selecting them in the select query.

```
SELECT x.a, y.b z.c FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y ,(SELECT * FROM c) as z
```

[Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to sql fiddle to test your query